# How can I delete comment on deleted post state?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Having good amount reputation , I can see the deleted post's on SO.

But recently came to know that I can even delete the comments in that post even in deleted state. What is the point of giving that permission to delete ?

Previously I cannot do that. It seems a recent change. May I know the reason/policy for this ?

Comment: You were always able to delete your own comments, irrespective of the state of the post. What makes you think this is a recent change?

Comment: I don't think this is a recent change, but perhaps your definition of "recent" is different. ;) But I guess you can still delete comments for the very same reasons as you could normally delete comments.

Comment: previously I cannot do this. i used to get a message like `comments cannot be add/delete on deleted post`..so and so ..i f I remember correctly.

Comment: You cannot *add* more comments on a deleted post, no. You'd get that message if the post was deleted after you opened the page and tried to comment on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The same thing why not applied for votes ? I cannot upvote or downvote or even recast my vote.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Why *shouldn't* you be able to delete your own comments? Voting affects others, deleting comments does not. Comments are second class citizens anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If the post is deleted in the first place, **does it matter if you are able to**?

I mean what would be the advantage of not being able to do it?

Comment: I got the same doubt and tried to un down vote. But failed.